# alphabetic indexer in android

Tags: android, indexer

I have a list view populated from the database, I have my scroll view with FastScroll enabled, the scroll bar is showing the widget but the indexing is not working
can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post..[AlphabetizedAdapter](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/02/10/Implementing-a-ListView-with-AlphabetIndexer-and-CursorAdapter-on-Android). This will help you.

According to [AlphabetIndexer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html), an AlphabetIndexer is:

> A helper class for adapters that implement the SectionIndexer
>   interface. If the items in the adapter are sorted by simple
>   alphabet-based sorting, then this class provides a way to do fast
>   indexing of large lists using binary search. It caches the indices
>   that have been determined through the binary search and also
>   invalidates the cache if changes occur in the cursor.Your adapter is
>   responsible for updating the cursor by calling `setCursor(Cursor)` if
>   the cursor changes. `getPositionForSection(int)` method does the binary
>   search for the starting index of a given section (alphabet).

So you might consider using a [Cursor Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)  and implement a [Section Indexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html).